# Reduce Pollyfill

Tags: javascript, apply, call, reduce

I was playing around with this array reduce polyfill and I'm just confused why is he/she using `apply`. I know that `apply` adds `this` context in the execution. But I don't know why we need it here, I just tried without it, and it works fine too.

```
Array.prototype.reduce = function (cb, initialValue) {
  console.log('inside my reducer');
  if (!cb || typeof cb !== 'function') throw TypeError();
  var len = this.length;
  var i = 0;
  console.log('this', this);
  if (typeof initialValue === 'undefined' || initialValue === null) {
    initialValue = this[0];
    ++i;
  }

  for (; i < len; i++) {
    initialValue = cb.apply(this, [initialValue, this[i], i, this]);

    //comment the line above and uncomment this line and it will work fine
    //initialValue = cb(initialValue, this[i]); 
    
  }

  return initialValue;
};
```

```
[1, 2, 1, 1].reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0); => 5
```

So, I'm a little confused, if anyone could share some insights it'll be apreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: "*I just tried without it, and it works fine too.*" did you try it with a callback that uses `this`?

Comment: @VLAZ - [`reduce`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-array.prototype.reduce) doesn't offer any special handling of that case, unlike `map` or `filter`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it's still strange to say "I know `.apply()` changes the value of `this`, so I tested it with a function that does not use `this`"

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Apparently the author of the polyfill assumed that `this` is the array being reduced.

Comment: Sometimes I'm afraid to ask because of answers like @VLAZ, but then T.J Crowder appears and I'm glad that I asked the question. No matter how stupid sounds to VLAZ today I've learned something. Thanks, T.C CCrowser

Answer (score 1):

Wherever you got that polyfill, it's incorrect, in a couple of ways but in particular that `initialValue = cb.apply(this, [initialValue, this[i], i, this]);` should be using `undefined`, not `this`, in the first argument. [`reduce`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-array.prototype.reduce) always calls its callback with `this` set to `undefined` (it'll end up being the global object if the callback is in loose mode rather than strict mode). So either `initialValue = cb.apply(undefined, [initialValue, this[i], i, this]);` or (more directly) `initialValue = cb(initialValue, this[i], i, this);`

Separately, it makes no sense to use `apply` and create an array to provide to it rather than using `call` with the discrete values it already has. Also, continuing to use something called `initialValue` for the accumulator is, at best, misleading. **And** it doesn't handle it correctly if you do `[].reduce(x => x)` (it should throw an error, not return `undefined` [note no seed value]).

So basically, I wouldn't put much faith in that polyfill, since it's providing the array, rather than `undefined`, as `this` during callbacks.

Comment: Or maybe instead of passing undefined you pass -> `(function() { return !this; })() ? window : undefined`,  yeah, I know it's been pedantic.. :)

Comment: @Keith The specification specifically says that it should be called with `undefined` as the `thisArg`.

Comment: @Barmar  Not sure about the spec, but Chrome is not passing undefined.. :(  Or neither does Firefox..

Comment: @Keith - It is, actually, but the value gets changed on receipt at the function: When you call a loose mode function with `undefined` for `this`, the global object is substituted instead when the `undefined` is received, because loose mode functions can't have a primitive value for `this`. So `fn.call(undefined)` if `fn` is a loose mode function ends up with `this` set to the global object during the call. Use strict mode. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  Yeah, that's why I said I was been pedantic, who uses loose mode, and even if they did depends on `this` been the global window..

Comment: @Keith - What matters is the **callback** function being loose, not the `reduce` function. That's why that code is unnecessary. It doesn't matter whether the **caller** is loose or strict, what matters is the **callee**.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder  Ah, see.. Didn't know call did that with `undefined`.  That's why I come to SO, seem to learn little nuggets everyday..